# How to control image height within a "Rendered Entity" that displays images & text fields within a View?

Tags: views, theming, media

I currently have a view that displays (1) Image field and (2) Text fields. This view is

- HTML List view of
- Rendered Entities

The Rendered Entities is the default "Product List" view mode from Commerce Kickstarter.

When I try to set a "min-height" for this field, the css is applied to all items within the field, which isn't what I'm after. I want to set a min-height for the image, so that the grid is consistent across the row.

```
.view-collection-products .view-content .item-list .products-per-collection li .commerce-product-field, .view-collection-taxonomy-term .view-content .item-list .products-per-collection li .commerce-product-field {
color: #000000;
font-size: 14px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
/* min-height: 300px; */
```

}

Without it, the text fields jog up and down, adjusting to the image height.
[image]

How do I re-write the css so that it targets just the image field in this view?

Answer (score 1):

To restrict your css rule only on the image just add "img" to your actual css :

```
.view-collection-products .view-content .item-list .products-per-collection li .commerce-product-field, .view-collection-taxonomy-term .view-content .item-list .products-per-collection li .commerce-product-field img {
    min-height: 300px;
    }
```

But if you want to be sure to have consistent rows, you should directly fix a height.

```
.view-collection-products .view-content .item-list .products-per-collection li .commerce-product-field, .view-collection-taxonomy-term .view-content .item-list .products-per-collection li .commerce-product-field img {
height: 300px;
}
```

Or at least use max-height whereas min-height.

Comment: Is there a means of setting the height dynamically for mobile-friendly use? My goal is to set the container to a consistent height, but not force the images to scale. It would also be great to have the images vertically align center :)

Comment: What expected behavior do you want ?

Comment: In terms of dynamic response, I would want the container height max to shrink down to 100px (maybe) for a mobile device. Right now most of my image heights are set to "auto" with a width at 100% so the image simply fills the available space.

Comment: You have to yser media queries for that : `@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { .view-collection-products .view-content .item-list .products-per-collection li { height: 50vh;}}` will make your entire field (image + description) fit half of the screen height, so users could see two products on the screen.